# Speed up runhaskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a small test framework. It executes a loop which does the following:

1. Generate a small Haskell source file.
2. Execute this with `runhaskell`. The program generates various disk files.
3. Process the disk files just generated.

This happens a few dozen times. It turns out that `runhaskell` is taking up the vast majority of the program's execution time.

On one hand, the fact that `runhaskell` manages to load a file from disk, tokenise it, parse it, do dependency analysis, load 20KB more text from disk, tokenise and parse all of this, perform complete type inference, check types, desugar to Core, link against compiled machine code, and execute the thing in an interpreter, all inside of 2 seconds of wall time, is actually pretty damned impressive when you think about it. On the other hand, I still want to make it go faster. ;-)

Compiling the tester (the program that runs the above loop) produced a tiny performance difference. Compiling the 20KB of library code that the scripts link against produced a rather more noticeable improvement. But it's still taking about 1 second per invocation of `runhaskell`.

The generated Haskell files are just over 1KB each, but only one part of the file actually changes. Perhaps compiling the file and using GHC's `-e` switch would be faster?

Alternatively, maybe it's the overhead of repeatedly creating and destroying many OS processes which is slowing this down? Every invocation of `runhaskell` presumably causes the OS to explore the system search path, locate the necessary binary file, load it into memory (surely this is already in the disk cache?), link it against whatever DLLs, and fire it up. Is there some way I can (easily) keep one instance of GHC running, rather than having to constantly create and destroy the OS process?

Ultimately, I suppose there's always the GHC API. But as I understand it, that's nightmarishly difficult to use, highly undocumented, and prone to radical changes at every minor point release of GHC. The task I'm trying to perform is only very simple, so I don't really want to make things more complex than necessary.

Suggestions?

**Update:** Switching to `GHC -e` (i.e., now *everything* is compiled except the one expression being executed) made no measurable performance difference. It seems pretty clear at this point that it's all OS overhead. I'm wondering if I could maybe create a pipe from the tester to GHCi and thus make use of just one OS process...

Comment: Your whole workflow doesn't look exactly performance-aimed, does it? Why do you have to create Haskell code?

Comment: Obviously you need a GHC daemon! :p (some people I know used to joke about creating a grep daemon to avoid the overhead of continually calling grep during boot, etc.)

Comment: +1 for a justified and well-executed attempt at optimization.

Comment: Not sure how well it performs, but have you considered using [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) or [hint-server](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-server)?

Comment: `ghc -O --make Main && ./program.exe`

Comment: @DanBurton +1 for mentioning `hint`, which I've never heard of. I don't think it can solve this specific problem (due to the requirement of redirecting `stdout`), but it could be useful in future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, I have a solution: I created a single GHCi process and connected its `stdin` to a pipe, so that I can send it expressions to interactively evaluate.

Several fairly large program refactorings later, and the entire test suite now takes roughly 8 seconds to execute, rather than 48 seconds. That'll do for me! :-D

(To anyone else trying to do this: *For the love of God*, remember to pass the `-v0` switch to GHCi, or you'll get a GHCi welcome banner! Weirdly, if you run GHCi interactively, even with `-v0` the command prompt still appears, but when connected to a pipe the command prompt vanishes; I'm presuming this is a helpful design feature rather than an random accident.)

---

Of course, half the reason I'm going down this strange route is that I want to capture `stdout` and `stderr` to a file. Using `RunHaskell`, that's quite easy; just pass the appropriate options when creating the child process. But now *all* of the test cases are being run by a single OS process, so there's no obvious way to redirect `stdin` and `stdout`.

The solution I came up with was to direct all test output to a single file, and between tests have GHCi print out a magic string which (I hope!) won't appear in test output. Then quit GHCi, slurp up the file, and look for the magic strings so I can snip the file into suitable chunks.

Comment: Can you change your test functions so they take handles for out and error rather than writing directly to stdout and stderr?

Answer (score 3):

You might find some useful code in [TBC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TBC). It has different ambitions - in particular to scrap test boilerplate and test projects that may not compile completely - but it could be extended with a watch-directory feature. The tests are run in GHCi but objects successfully built by cabal ("runghc Setup build") are used.

I developed it to test EDSLs with complicated type hackery, i.e. where the heavy computational lifting is done by other libraries.

I am presently updating it to the latest Haskell Platform and welcome any comments or patches.

Answer (score 2):

If the majority of the source files remain unchanged, you can possibly use GHC's `-fobject-code` (possibly in conjunction with `-outputdir`) flag to compile some of the library files.

Comment: As I said, I've _already_ compiled the 20KB of library code. That reduced run time from 2 seconds to 1 second. But I'd like to reduce this further if there's an easy way to do so.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Oh, missed that bit sorry :s

Answer (score 0):

If calling `runhaskell` takes so much time then perhaps you should eliminate it completely?

If you really need to work with changing Haskell code then you can try the following.

1. Create a set of modules with varying contents as needed.
2. Each module should export it's main function
3. Additional wrapper module should execute the right module from the set based on input arguments. Each time you want to execute a single test you would use a different arguments.
4. The whole program is compiled statically

Example module:

```
module Tester where

import Data.String.Interpolation -- package Interpolation

submodule nameSuffix var1 var2 = [str|
module Sub$nameSuffix$ where

someFunction x = $var1$ * x
anotherFunction v | v == $var2$ = v
                  | otherwise = error ("anotherFunction: argument is not " ++ $:var2$)

|]

modules = [ let suf = (show var1 ++ "_" ++ show var2)  in (suf,submodule suf var1 var2) | var1 <- [1..10], var2 <- [1..10]]

writeModules = mapM_ (\ (file,what) -> writeFile file what) modules
```

Comment: That's not really going to work. Some of the test programs may crash; if the whole thing was one giant program, that would stop it running. Also, I want to capture `stdout` and `stderr` from each test and log these to file. Were it not for that, then yes, I could just generate the entire thing as one single giant Haskell program. That would be much easier...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: You re-execute the program for each test, so as long as everything compiles you will be fine. Regarding redirection: what is wrong with `./testRunner testNumber123 2>stderr.txt 1>stdout.txt` ?

Comment: What does "crash" mean? You should be able to integrate all of your tests into a single program, and invoke them with a top-level test runner that deals with redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` and recovering from crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If the tests are well isolated from one another, you can put all the test code into a single program and invoke `runhaskell` once.  This may not work if some tests are created based on the results of others, or if some tests call `unsafeCrash`.

I presume your generated code looks like this

```
module Main where
boilerplate code
main = do_something_for_test_3
```

You can put the code of all the tests into one file.  Each test code generator is responsible for writing `do_something_for_test_N`.

```
module Main where
boilerplate code

-- Run each test in its own directory
withTestDir d m = do
  cwd <- getCurrentDirectory
  createDirectory d
  setCurrentDirectory d
  m
  setCurrentDirectory cwd

-- ["test1", "test2", ...]
dirNames = map ("test"++) $ map show [1..] 
main = zipWithM withTestDir dirNames tests

-- Put tests here
tests =
  [ do do_something_for_test_1
  , do do_something_for_test_2
  , ...
  ]
```

Now you only incur the overhead of a single call to `runhaskell`.